# Does JSON.Net support multiple contract resolvers

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am serializing an object using Newtonsoft [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).  I want to ignore some properties of the object I am serializing and I don't have the source code for that object so I am not able to decorate the property with a `JsonIgnore` attribute.  I found a [custom](https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/JsonDotNetCustomContractResolvers) resolver that will allow me to do this.  Unfortunately I was also hoping to use the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` as well.  Since I cannot specify two resolvers I am trying to determine what is the best way to solve my issue.

Here is my code...

```
var resolver = new PropertiesContractResolver();
resolver.ExcludeProperties.Add("Package.Count");

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    // I want to be able to also use PropertiesContractResolver
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(package, settings);
```

Is there a way to do what I am attempting?

---

**EDIT**

I found the solution.  You can set the `NamingStrategy` property found on the DefaultContractResolver (the base class of `PropertiesContractResolver` to `CamelCaseNamingStrategy`.

```
var resolver = new PropertiesContractResolver
{       
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()  
};
```

Comment: How would you expect multiple resolvers to actually be invoked?  What order would they run in?  Which would take precedence?

Comment: @DavidL I don't know much about the inner workings of JSON.Net but couldn't they set them up to work the same as Converters?  What order do Converters run in?

Comment: A converter is per type that is converted.  A resolver is per serialization of the entire payload.  Do you see the issue?  See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm for further details.

Comment: @DavidL  Oh yes I do now.  Let me clarify the question.  Maybe someone can help me determine how to do what I am trying to do.  Thanks.  I always think I am being clear until people starting helping me!

Comment: You can chain resolvers.  It's basically the decorator pattern.  e.g. if resolver A can't return a contract, it calls resolver B, who calls resolver C, etc.  In my code here I have two decorators on my contract resolver.

Comment: This is very similar to the one identified as an exact duplicate except both resolvers I want to use are third-party resolvers.  But the duplicate does answer the question that it is not possible to have multiple resolvers.